# System.OutOfMemoryException" error in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, .net, out-of-memory

I am encountering a "System.OutOfMemoryException" error while working in Visual Studio 2019. This error message appears when I try to run my code or perform certain actions in the IDE. I have tried restarting Visual Studio and my computer, but the error persists. Can someone help me understand what is causing this error and how to fix it?
[image]

I try to Increase my system's virtual memory.

Comment: How much memory do you have installed? How much page file space do you have? Do you have any oddball extensions installed? How big is your solution? The last solution I worked on had 63 projects and 4000-5000 files. Is it bigger than that? Is the solution purely managed code (C# or VB), purely native code (C, C++) or mixed mode?

Comment: Are you sure the IDE crashes and not your software? Does your software run fine outside of the IDE?

Comment: @rene yes outside the ide my software working fine but issue inside visual studio 2019

Comment: @AbubakrSiddique I'm assuming this is a component of VS throwing this exception as if it would be VS itself it would just crash. After the exception is reported, is there something in the windows event viewer that might give more information about what caused that?

Comment: If you watch Resource Monitor does it show that Visual Studio is consuming a large amount of memory? Is another process consuming a large amount of memory when you launch Visual Studio? If you open another project or create a starter project does the same issue occur?

Comment: @mperry this issue is occur just for vs "This issue occurs only in Visual Studio. When this issue occurs, I close Visual Studio and reopen the project, which resolves the error.